# How do I print a 2-Dimensional array as a grid in Golang?

Tags: go

[The 2D Array I am trying to print as a board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq9Fd.png)

Note: I am a complete novice at using Go and need this for a final project.

I am making an attempt to make the game, snake and ladders. I need to print a 10x10 2D array as a grid so it can look more like a board.

I've tried using:

```
                 for row := 0; row < 10; row ++ 10{
                   } for column := 0; column < 10; column++{
                   fmt.Println()
                   }
```

But it fails.

Any function or any method to do so?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and describe what problems you have. Aim for a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you should pass the variable you want to print to [`fmt.Println`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println). Also keep in mind that this will always add a newline to the end of the output. You can use the [`fmt.Print`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Print) function to just print the variable.

```golang
for row := 0; row < 10; row++ {
    for column := 0; column < 10; column++{
        fmt.Print(board[row][column], " ")
    }
    fmt.Print("\n")
}
```

Bonus tip, instead of using hardcoded sizes you can also use [range](https://gobyexample.com/range) to loop over each element which works for arrays/slices of any size.

Answer (score 0):

### Range-Based Solution

Ranges save us from passing the length directly, and so could make the function re-usable for 2D arrays of differing heights and widths. ([Go By Example range page](https://gobyexample.com/range)).

##### A general purpose 2D matrix iterator

Using a range to loop over every value in a 2D array might look like ...

[Run this code in Go playground here](https://go.dev/play/p/FjPIaVU4Enz)

```
// Code for some "board" matrix of type [][]int, for example...
board := [][]int{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
}


// First we iterate over "board", which is an array of rows:
for r, _ := range board {

    // Then we iterate over the items of each row:
    for c, colValue := range board[r] {

        // See string formatting docs at 
        // https://gobyexample.com/string-formatting
        fmt.Printf("value at index [%d][%d]", r, c)
        fmt.Println(" is", colValue)
    }
}
```

##### What the underscores mean

Underscores are necessary where declared variables would not be used, or the (compiler?) will throw an error and won't run the code.

The variables `r` and `c` are used to give us ongoing access to integer indexes within the matrix, starting at 0 and counting up. We have to pass an underscore `_` there after the `r` because that space would give us access to the whole row object, which we don't ever use later in the code. (Yes, we could alternatively have defined `range row` instead of `range board[r]`, and then we would be using the row object. )

We also would have had to pass a `_` in position of `c` if we hadn't later used `c`  in the Printf statement. Here is a simpler version (and [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/E6gGfYbdKav)) with no index-access:

```
// Just prints all the values. 
for _, row := range board {
    for _, colValue := range row {
        fmt.Println(colValue)
    }
}
```

##### why is "colValue" and not "col" ?

In this pattern, some telling name like "`colValue`" is used instead of `column`. This is because at this inner point in the code, we have drilled down to a single element instead of a whole set of elements like by accessing whole rows with `board[r]`

Here, we don't use the indices at all, so they have to be written with `_`.